# SSRS: Parameters do not return all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I use a stored procedure with two parameters for my SSRS report.
Parameters:
@ParaID -> no available values
@ParaCountryCode -> has available values

Both parameters are multi-value fields.

I tried the following code without success. It will return data but only a part of it.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @ParaID varchar(255),
    @ParaCountryCode varchar(4)
as
if (exists(select * from dbo.MVSplit(@ParaID,',') where Item = '%'))
set @ParaID = null
SELECT        *
FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
where 
@ParaID is NULL or table1.ID in (select Item from dbo.MVSplit(@ParaID,',')) and table2.CountryCode in (select Item from dbo.MVSplit(@ParaCountryCode,','))
```

I changed the expression for parameters to: =Join(Parameters!ParaID.Value,",") and =Join(Parameters!ParaCountryCode.Value,",")

Result:

```
ID | Country
1     GER
2     GER
```

Expected Result

```
ID | Country
1     GER
2     GER
2     UK
2     US
```

I also tried to solve that problem with a subquery something like:

```
Select *
From 
(
Select * from FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
where 
@ParaID is NULL or table1.ID in (select Item from dbo.MVSplit(@ParaID,','))
) as Inntertable
where table2.CountryCode in (select Item from dbo.MVSplit(@ParaCountryCode,','))
```

But it did not solve my issue either.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve the problem?